# Crystal Reports crosstab

Tags: crystal-reports, crosstab

I am new to crystal reports so this might be novice to you.

I have created a cross tab with row grand total to the right. How can I add an extra column to display Average of the rows. I am using Crystal reports 2008

Here is a rough example of the cross tab- How do I insert the Average column? Thanks

```
        New York   Chicago     Boston     Total       Average
```

Gross Sales

Answer (score 9):

Crystal doesn't allow you to add additional columns to crosstabs at the same level of grouping, and it repeats any summarised values at all levels of summarisation. However, the following should achieve what you want:

1. Create a dummy formula, set to a constant value (eg. " ").
2. In the Cross-Tab Expert, add your dummy formula to the list of column items as the first item.
3. In the Cross-Tab Expert, you should already have sum of gross sales in the list of Summarized Fields. Drag the gross sales figure from the list of Available Fields into the Summarized Fields, so that sum of gross sales appears twice in the Summarized Fields, highlight the second sum and click on the Change Summary... button to change the summary operation from Sum to Average. Click on the OK button in the Edit Summary dialog to return to the Cross-Tab Expert, where Sum and Avg of gross sales will be listed in the Summarized Fields, then click on the OK button to confirm these changes.
4. You will now have a Crosstab with an additional summary column and two summarised values in each summary cell. Select all of the average values in the Group Columns using Ctrl-Click, right-click and select Format Objects... and check the Suppress option. Click on OK - those values should now be greyed out.
5. Select all of the total (but not the average) values in the grand Total column using Ctrl-Click, right-click and select Format Objects... and check the Suppress option. Click on OK - those values should now be greyed out.
6. Edit the text box for the grand Total column and change it to say Average.
7. Preview the report - you should now have a column of Average gross sales to the right of your Total Gross Sales.

Crosstabs are really **not** Crystal's strongest point.

Comment: "Crosstabs are really not Crystal's strongest point." --- Wish I could express this to my boss!

Comment: Helpful, thanks. I don't suppose there's a way to get the dummy "total" to appear _before_ the other columns, while the real total stays to the right? I'm actually trying to list employee + SSN down the left side, in two columns.  (Already got it working with string concatenation in one column, but that's not good for Excel export.) I can "extract" the SSN with a "max" function, but as best I can tell, all total columns (real or fake) will appear together.

Answer (score 1):

do it on the back end instead of with Crystal.  You want Crystal to do the least amount of data manipulation possible, as it's a reporting tool.

Comment: Sure I can do the that. But how do I insert an additional column in my cross tab to display the average numbers

Comment: forget the Crystal solution, use whatever your back-end tool is (SQL Server?) to add the additional col (in a second view, for example, in SQL Server.)  I'm assuming you can modify the report's datasource directly, but if not, you can modify it with whatever tool you have in another step before using the datasource in the report.

Comment: the OP is trying to use a crosstab, ie. to pivot the data. This is one case where it is normally better to do it in the presentation layer (ie. Crystal, here) rather than the data layer - even though Crystal's crosstabs *suck*.

Comment: Beth... I agree with your point +1.... On the other hand I've been directed by management at my company to only use CR so that co-workers can edit my files. So disregarding logic there are cases when you have to do it the round about way. (If you can figure it out.)

Comment: You will still use CR, and they will still be able to edit your files, you're just taking the crosstab step upstream to your datasource.